# scraping, help needed, using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the link that pops up as the result of the search, but the code says that I found nothing

```py
    my_url = 'https://wormbase.org/search/gene/R04B5.4a'
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    links = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"result result-gene  tip-simple star"})
```

Comment: link that pops up - It is most likely rendered afterwards with Javascript you can use something like https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div that you are looking for is loaded by javascript, not in the original html. Beautifulsoup can only find divs that are in the html itself. The best way to get content like this is to find *where* the javascript is loading the content from. To do this, I recommend simply opening developer tools with `f12` and refreshing the page and looking for `xhr` requests. In your case, the data is being loaded from

`https://wormbase.org/search/gene/R04B5.4a/1?inline=1`

If you run your code on this page instead, you will get results. If you need to do other queries from this site, you can replace the `R04B5.4a` part with other queries.

EDIT:
In your browser (chrome, firefox, internet explorer, etc), go to the webpage that you want to scrape. Press f12 on your keyboard, and you should see the Developer Tools come up.  It should have a tab that says elements, console, etc.

You want to go to the tab that says "Network". Then refresh the page. You should see a whole bunch of requests appear in the network tab. Those are all of the requests made when you load the page. Those requests have a "type".

XHR requests represent data being sent between the server and your computer. Look for requests that have the type XHR and one or more of those will have the data that you are looking for.

Usually (depending on your browser) if you double click on the each request it will open in a new tab and show you what it contains. Once you find the request that has the data you want, you can simply take the URL for that request and use it instead.

In your case, the link I put above is the link for the XHR request that retrieves the search results.

Comment: Im sorry im a beginner, can you please elaborate on the f12 and xhr requests mean

Comment: I really appreciate the response, Im still new and have been learning on my own. I understand what you were implying, but I still dont understand how to create a simple XHR request. May I ask for help on that also, if you have time

Comment: Sorry, I see the confusion: you don't need to worry about the type of request. Just use that url like you would any other link with uReq. The endpoint here is just html that you can parse normally with beautifulsoup.